# Issue with importing keras in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: ipython

I have an issue while importing keras after installing Tensorflow and Keras using Anaconda Prompt. The error says 'No module named keras'. I'm using Python 3.67.

Answer (score 0):

As a start:

1) Try `pip list | grep Keras` and check for latest

2) Try `pip list | grep tensorflow` and check for 1.5

If not something went wrong with the install. If so, the next thing I'd try is

3) `conda update --all` (probably worth trying anyway)

4) `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` and `pip install --upgrade keras` ... see https://inmachineswetrust.com/posts/deep-learning-setup/ step 3 which tells us keras isn't officially available on conda.

5) If you've messed around with your environment, I'd suggest doing a `brew cleanup` and `brew cask cleanup`

6) Look into virtual environments if you haven't. Probably better to mess around with that than your base env